# Can't change string with Rails' String#camelize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, camelcasing

Ruby is not my normal language, and I'm struggling to get the following to work.

I'm just working with an array.

```
irb(main):54232:0> contact_data
=> ["3521", "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com", "ADA JONES SMITH"]

irb(main):54226:0> contact_data[2].split.first.to_s.camelize
=> "ADA"
```

Why? and how do I convert the string to CamelCase?

Thank you.

Comment: Erm what string?....

Comment: Do you use rails, don't you? Please, add rails tag to question. It's a bit unclear what string is used. Also "ada".camelize gives "Ada" for rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`downcase`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html#method-i-downcase):

```
contact_data[2].split.first.to_s.downcase.camelize
```

Also [`titleize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize) is useful method for your task.

```
2.1.2 :002 > "ADA".titleize
 => "Ada"
```

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me insane.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `contact_data[2].split.first` is already completely upcase: `"ADA"`, and the method `String#camelize` works on lowercase strings.

You should make it lowercase first:

```
contact_data[2].split.first.to_s.downcase.camelize
```